# How do I filter a view in Xpages by date (today's date)

Tags: xpages

I cannot get my filter to work when filtering by date.

I have a view with a categorized date in the first field.

In the filter by Category field I have

```
   session.createDateTime(@Today()).getDateOnly()
```

I have also tried typing in "May 23, 2014" and so on.

One question - what is the filter working on, the underlying view or the xpages data?

Comment: Clarification: Are you using the categoryFilter property on the view data source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to use categoryFilter on an existing view, I'm afraid the answer may be "it won't work" - I don't recall ever making it work, and my testing now didn't result in anything. The problem is similar to (probably exactly the same as) view.createViewNavFromCategory() - it wants a string, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get Domino to deal with a date there instead.

So that leaves a couple options. The "keys" parameter does indeed take a DateTime, but loses further categorization. If that's fine, you could accomplish it by tweaking your code slightly:

```
var dt = session.createDateTime(@Today());
dt.setAnyTime();
dt
```

The ".getDateOnly()" method actually returns a localized string representing the date, not a DateTime without time information.

Alternatively, if you're alright with modifying the view, I recommend changing the Date column to a locale-neutral string, such as:

```
@Text(@Year(Date)) + "-" + @Text(@Month(Date)) + "-" + @Text(@Day(Date))
```

Then, you can use a category filter like this:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d").format(@Today())
```

Comment: I went the route of changing the view column, kind of like you suggested. And it works. Thanks!